# loop through list of Tuple

Tags: python

I have a list of a tuples and I want to iterate through it and calculate the total cost. I want to get the total cost of orange plus the total cost of the banana. For example, `5.26*8 + 2.00* 10` to find out the total cost.

How do I access these values? I try to access for example `5.26 using b[1]*b[2]` but I get an error.

```
def totalcost(shoping):
    for a in shoping:
        for b in a:
        total1=b[1]*b[2]
        print(total1)

shoping=[("orange",5.26,8),("banana",2.00,10)]
totalcost(shoping)
```

Comment: Indent your code properly (the last 2 lines of *totalcost*).

Comment: `b` is "Orange", you are trying to multiple "r" with "a".

Comment: Posting the error you get will help us answer faster :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to *unpack* each tuple into three variables:

```
def get_total_cost(shopping):
    total_cost = 0
    for line_item in shopping:
        product, cost, quantity = line_item  # Unpack the tuple
        total_cost += quantity * cost
    return total_cost

shopping=[("orange", 5.26, 8), ("banana", 2.00, 10)]
print(get_total_cost(shopping))
```

One can combine the unpacking with the loop:

```
def get_total_cost(shopping):
    total_cost = 0
    for product, cost, quantity in shopping:
        total_cost += quantity * cost
    return total_cost
```

It is possible to write the entire computation as a single [generator expression](https://dbader.org/blog/python-generator-expressions):

```
def get_total_cost(shopping):
    return sum(quantity * cost for product, cost, quantity in shopping)
```

I gave `product` a name for clarity.  However, in code like this it is customary to see `_` in place of unused variables:

```
def get_total_cost(shopping):
    return sum(quantity * cost for _, cost, quantity in shopping)
```

For completeness, I'll mention that it is possible to access tuple elements by index:

```
    return sum(line_item[1] * line_item[2] for line_item in shopping)
```

though to my eye this is significantly less readable than using named variables.

Finally, if you're on Python 3.7 ([or 3.6](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses)) you should consider using [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html).  If you're using an earlier version of Python, [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) is an option.

Answer (score 0):

You have tuple in **for** loop in **a** so you can slice values from that tuple.

```
def totalcost(shoping):
    for a in shoping:
        total1=a[1]*a[2]
        print(total1)

shoping=[("orange",5.26,8),("banana",2.00,10)]
totalcost(shoping)
```